# Ledger hardware wallet recovery phrase is identical for both Bitcoin and Ethereum wallets on it?

Tags: recovery, hardware-wallets

When you buy a Ledger Nano X, you generate its recovery or seed phrase consisting of 24 words. Is this seed phrase always inseparable between the Bitcoin wallet app and the Ethereum wallet app that you would install inside of the Ledger?

Wouldn't people rather have a seed phrase for the Bitcoin wallet, and a separate seed phrase for their Ethereum wallet?

If in fact conjoined in hardware wallets, is there anyway to disentangle or separate the wallet's seed phrase into 2 distinct seed phrases for each?